# How do you change the state of multiple tkinter buttons when your mouse is pressed and hovering over it?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, lambda, mouseover

I have a 2d array of tkinter buttons.

It looks like this:
[image]

I want to be able to click on a button, hold my mouse down, and every button that is hovered over while my mouse is pressed down changes colors. So far I have it to the point where if you hover over any square regardless if a mouse button is pressed it changes colors.

The code looks like this so far:

```
def draw(self, i, j):
    button = self.buttons[i][j] 
    button.bind('<Enter>', lambda event: self.on_enter(event, button))


def on_enter(self, e, button):
    button['background'] = 'green'
```

To be clear, I want to be able to change a button's color when left-click is held down and a button is hovered over at the same time.

Thanks for helping me.

EDIT: removed picture of code and provided something that can be copy and pasted.

2ND EDIT: the code is about 100 lines, but the gist is there's a 2d array of tkinter buttons, and the code I provided shows the 2 functions responsible for changing the color of the buttons. If more code is needed, I'll put it in.

Comment: Include code as text, not as images, as it wont be able to copy pasted and run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind `<B1-Motion>` on root window to a callback. Then inside the callback, use `.winfo_pointerxy()` to get the mouse position and `.winfo_containing()` to find which button is under the mouse pointer and change its background color:

Example:

```py
def on_drag(event):
    x, y = root.winfo_pointerxy()
    btn = root.winfo_containing(x, y)
    if btn:
        btn.config(bg="green")

# root is the root window
root.bind('<B1-Motion>', on_drag)
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying. I'll try implementing that solution tomorrow since it's 3 am for me. Thanks, this was useful.

Comment: Worked flawlessly. Thank you so much, I was really stuck.